# How to set job failure alerts in oozie?

Tags: oozie, hue, oozie-workflow

I am oozie on Hue interface where i would like to get the email alerts for any killed/Failed/long runnig jobs.

Is there any way to get this.

Below is the component  list:

Component   Version
  Hue       2.6.1
  HDP       2.3.6
  Hadoop    2.7.1
  Oozie     4.2.0
  Ambari    2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below action

```
 <action name="ErrorHandler">
        <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
            <to>${notify}</to>
            <subject>FAILURE - Automated email notification for process</subject>
            <body>The upload process for <Process name> failed.</body>
        </email>
        <ok to="error"/>
        <error to="error"/>
    </action>
```

Few points to remember -

1. In job.properties, mention the required email address for the notify variable.
2. Set SMTP hostname and port in oozie-site.xml